# PHP Regular Expression HTML

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a `$source` var which I get with curl and contains the following commented out string

```
//"url":"http://lh5.ggpht.com/_EpgGIto9934/TKXKqAw7uFI/AAAAAAAAGrM/PrQiCNyUdEo/8827.jpg","
$regex = "!url/"/:/"(.*)8827/.jpg!U";
preg_match_all($regex, $source, $res);
var_dump($res);
```

I want to get the `http://.....jpg` address
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What kind of string is that? Where does it come from? I don't think this needs a Regex

Comment: Also for what you were doing wrong: the escaping. It's \ backslash, not `/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like json. If that's the case you won't need regular expressions for that. You can just use json_decode

```
<?php

$s = "//\"url\":\"http://lh5.ggpht.com/_EpgGIto9934/TKXKqAw7uFI/AAAAAAAAGrM/PrQiCNyUdEo/8827.jpg\",\"";

$regex = '/http(.+)\.jpg/';
preg_match($regex, $s, $matches);
echo $matches[0];

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$source = '"url":"http://lh5.ggpht.com/_EpgGIto9934/TKXKqAw7uFI/AAAAAAAAGrM/PrQiCNyUdEo/8827.jpg","';
$regex = '/^.*\/([^\/]+\.jpg).*$/';
preg_match($regex, $source, $res);
print_r($res);
$jpg = $res[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use that regex

```
http.+\....(?=",".+)
```

That will work for all 3 letters extensions.